# jQuery slideUp bugs after page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm experiencing some problems with jQuery's slideUp and slideDown functions. If you go to this site

[www.confide.re/confide](http://www.confide.re/confide)

and click on one of the boxes, it normally works fine, but after you scroll the page and it loads some more boxes, then the slide function bugs and does it twice for no reason, if you get what I mean.

Is this something I've done wrong somewhere or is this a known bug?

Thanks

Here is the code:

```
var state = 'down';

$('.overlay').click(function() {

     if(state == 'down') {
         $(this).next().slideDown(155);
         state = 'up';
     } else {
         $(this).next().slideUp(150);
         state = 'down';
}
```

.overlay is a transparent div on top of each of the boxes.

Comment: you really need to also post your codes or else we won't know what the  direct problem is.

Comment: It is not the same code on your site. Infinitysroll.js, line 50 : code called twice.

Comment: oh right, I've uploaded the latest code to the site now

Comment: Problem occurs when infinity scroll is used, check that part of the code. It seems that the event is defined more than one.

Comment: Try to not define your event in the AJAX success callback.

Comment: I didn't want to have to define it in the AJAX callback but the things load after the rest of the page so when I had it in the js of the index file it wasn't working

Comment: Use on() jQuery function to add event on dynamically created stuff

Comment: ooh thanks, what should I have as the argument of the on()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `click` event outside your ajax success callback like this (Use a better selector that `body`, it is just for the example)

```
$("body").on("click", ".overlay", function(e){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(150);
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
});
```

Comment: It doesn't bug anymore! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/chanckjh/Jak6Q/

html:

```
<div class="something">
    <div class="bar">

    </div>
</div>​
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.something').click(function() {
        $('.bar').slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

css:

```
.something{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.bar{
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}​
```

or like this for the child: http://jsfiddle.net/chanckjh/Jak6Q/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('.something').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.bar').slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had used slideToggle first but was experiencing the same problem so I thought switching to slideUp and slideDown could solve it, but alas the problem is there with both methods

Answer (score 0):

You can not share a single variable `state` amongst many elements which need to record their specific status. Instead, you have to keep state for each of the elements.